# Spring - WebSocket - Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am currently developing a Web Socket for internal and external requests. However, while trying to test the bidirectional connection via a Chrome command I received the following error:

> "Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Web Socket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/bidirectional");
    }

    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {    
        //register a new endpoint
        registry.addEndpoint("/blueframe").setAllowedOrigins("/*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/blueframe").setAllowedOrigins("/*").withSockJS();
    }
 }
```

JavaScript connection:

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://192.168.137.23:8080/blueframe');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    });
```

I already tried to see other posts with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i quitted using Webservices, instead i start using RabbitMQ for a bidirectional communication.

Regarding Web Socket Configuration, i am not the only one having this problem so i found a parcial solution: Downgrade the Spring version or use Socket handlers instead of StompEndpointRegistry interface.